# how to work a spacebar key in qline edit using with pyqt4

Tags: python, python-2.7, pyqt, pyqt4

This is my code,when i click a space bar pushbutton i want to move a  cursor forward to one position in line edit.

how to move the cursor one forward position in line edit.

Given bellow is my code:

```
import sys
from pyface.qt import QtGui, QtCore


class Example(QtGui.QWidget):

    def __init__(self):
        super(Example, self).__init__()


        self.initUI()

    def initUI(self):

        self.title = QtGui.QLabel('Title')


        self.titleEdit = QtGui.QLineEdit()
        self.btn = QtGui.QPushButton("spacebar")
        self.btn.clicked.connect(self.spacebar)



        grid = QtGui.QGridLayout()
        grid.setSpacing(10)

        grid.addWidget(self.title, 1, 0)
        grid.addWidget(self.titleEdit, 1, 1)
        grid.addWidget(self.btn, 2, 1)



        self.setLayout(grid)

        self.setGeometry(300, 300, 350, 300)
        self.setWindowTitle('Review')
        self.show()
    def spacebar(self):
        self.titleEdit.cursorForward(True,int=1)

def main():

    app = QtGui.QApplication(sys.argv)
    ex = Example()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())


if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

Comment: What do you mean with *space bar key*? Do you mean the QPushButton?

Comment: then better say QPushButton, what is the problem with your current code?

Comment: That information is important, add it to your question or do not you think that is relevant?

Comment: Nowhere does it point out what you're trying, just say what you want

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For these cases you must send a `QKeyEvent` and establish the focus after sending it:

```
def spacebar(self):
    key_event = QtGui.QKeyEvent(QtCore.QEvent.KeyPress, QtCore.Qt.Key_Space, QtCore.Qt.NoModifier, " ")
    QtCore.QCoreApplication.sendEvent(self.titleEdit, key_event)
    QtCore.QTimer.singleShot(0, self.titleEdit.setFocus)
```

Comment: @navyasri for future questions give more emphasis to the explanation of your problem and the explanation of your intent, not everyone understands you, we are not in your head, please read [ask]

Comment: sorry for the trouble sir